# how can i form a mongo best match query for below case to achieve performance

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, search, mongodb-query

for a collection as below

```
Document 1
    {
        "entity" : "university",
        "parEnityHRCHY" : "Planet>continent>country>state>city",
        "parEnityVal" : "earth>North America>Massachusetts>Boston",
        "entityVal" : [ 
            "MIT", 
            "Harvard",
            "New England"
        ]
    }
Document 2 
{
        "entity" : "university",
        "parEnityHRCHY" : "Planet>continent>country>state",
        "parEnityVal" : "earth>North America>Massachusetts",
        "entityVal" : [ 
            "A", 
            "B",
            "C"
        ]
    }
```

i want to fetch  the best match "entityVal" for the input "entity","parEnityHRCHY","parEnityVal"
if the value is not available at the exact match it should look recursively till the root.
for eg. in above case if  "university" value are not available at the city level it should look at the state level like

if matches exact below condition return result.

Input:
    "parEnityHRCHY" : "Planet>continent>country>state>city",
    "parEnityVal" : "earth>North America>Massachusetts>Boston",

else look at one level up

```
"parEnityHRCHY" : "Planet>continent>country>state",
"parEnityVal" : "earth>North America>Massachusetts",
```

and so on until the root element.

please suggest some approach, i am planning to use $text search , max number of documents in collection approx 1 Million, max HRCHY level 10.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @AnirudhBagri : the expected out put is as below if document 1 is not exist in database.for input  : "parEnityHRCHY":Planet>continent>country>state>city",
"parEnityVal" : "earth>North America>Massachusetts>Boston", Output:"entity" : "university",
            "entityVal" : [  "A", 
            "B",
            "C"
        ]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
db.doc.find({"parEnityHRCHY" : "Planet>continent>country>state",'parEnityVal':{$regex:"earth>North America>Massachusetts"}})
```

But I am not sure If you're looking for something like this.